# AngularJS: Number input model and $valid function not working when number incremented using stepUp() and stepDown()

Tags: angularjs, validation, input, numbers

I am trying to validate my angular form with a number input. I have styled my number input ( which i have not included in my demo) so that i use stepUp() and stepDown() to increment and decrement values.

Here's my demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/9aBCTI6hcCM0HhHimVnL?p=preview

form.numbah.$valid and the number's ng-model doesn't change when i used stepUp()/stepDown() to increment/decrement values.

I want to validate form when there's a change in the number input.

Thanks in advance!

```js
angular.module('plunker', [])

.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $document) {
  $scope.numbah = -1;
  $scope.stepup = function(){
    document.getElementById("test-input").stepUp();
    // $scope.numbah++;
  };
  $scope.stepdown = function(){
    document.getElementById("test-input").stepDown();
    // $scope.numbah--;
  };
  $scope.change = function (value){
    alert(value);
    
  };
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

input[type=number]{
  width: 40px;
}

div {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form>
      <p>Click stepdown/stepup buttons. You will see that form.numbah.$valid and numbah won't change</p>
      <p>But, If you click spin buttons inside number input, then everything works fine</p>
      <ng-form name="form">
      <input id="test-input" name="numbah" type="number" ng-model="numbah" min="1" max="3" />
      <div>form.numbah.$valid: {{form.numbah.$valid}}</div>
      <div>Value of number : {{numbah}}</div>
      <div>
      <input type="button" ng-click="stepup()" value="stepup">
      <input type="button" ng-click="stepdown()" value="stepdown">  
      </div>
      
      <div>form.$valid : {{form.$valid}}</div>
      </ng-form>
    </form>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are using way too older version of angular, if you upgrade you should be good http://plnkr.co/edit/wuQnZzluUSxTiSuLY11G?p=preview

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't work if i use stepUp() and stepDown() functions. Check this : http://plnkr.co/edit/MTYvDP3XlID7IiJK0qIl?p=preview